# Initialize replay memory and action value function Q

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am not sure I can ask this question here, but I will make an attempt.

I am trying to implement [Beat Atari with Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://becominghuman.ai/lets-build-an-atari-ai-part-1-dqn-df57e8ff3b26). They explained all steps very well, but they ask you to fill the gap in trying yourselves. I take that quite seriously, but I faced some problem. Here is a problem I have:

In the linked [article](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vmnih/docs/dqn.pdf), they explained every step how to implement the subject:

[image]

How do I have to *"Initialize replay memory D to capacity N"* and *"Initialize action-value function Q with random weights"*?

Maybe I messed up completely, but for the `atari_model()` function, did they mean

```
# With the functional API we need to define the inputs.
frames_input = keras.layers.Input(ATARI_SHAPE, name="frames")
actions_input = keras.layers.Input((n_actions,), name="mask")
```

**P.S.** Note that I use Keras as framework.